# Check pages already created in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm building a Gatsby website with lots of pages created via `createPages`. I'm fetching data from my API, from multiple endpoints.

The problem is that some of the data from the endpoints are repeated and I end up recreating pages that have already been built.

Is there a way to know which pages have already been built? Via querying the slug, for example?

Comment: Why don't you filter your data first before creating pages

Comment: What would be the unique identifier to determine if it's duplicate? The slug? Then you could store each generated slug in an array in the createPages foreach loop and check for duplicates.

Comment: @AlbertSkibinski that's actually what we ended up doing. Thanks! If you create an answer I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine your unique identifier for each page. For example, if the identifier is the slug then store each generated slug in an array in the `createPages` foreach loop and check for duplicates.

Example:

```
const existingSlugs = [];

result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
  if (!existingSlugs.includes(node.fields.slug)) {
    createPage({
      path: node.fields.slug,
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`),
      context: {
       slug: node.fields.slug,
      },
    })
    existingSlugs.push(node.field.slug);
  }
})
```

Make sure you check for all sources.